# $\iiint_M (x+y+z)\,dx\,dy\,dz$ over $M=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R^3}: 0≤z≤(x^2+y^2)^2≤81\}$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, multiple-integral, bounds-of-integration

$$\iiint_M (x+y+z)\,dx\,dy\,dz$$ over $M=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R^3}: 0≤z≤(x^2+y^2)^2≤81\}$. How would I express this with the correct bounds? Once I have the bounds I can continue on my own but I need the bounds, since this is the very first time encountering this type of boundering with the $M$. Any hints about the change of bounds would really help.

Comment: Can you draw the figure and post here? It will help

Comment: With like wolfram alpha? And which figure? Let me specify that I'm quite rusty on this since I learned with Wolfram Alpha.

Comment: or https://www.geogebra.org/3d

Comment: do I input x+y+z? Sorry I'm just having issues remembering how to do this

Comment: That is just integrand. The region is what is given in inequalities

Comment: While I did post the answer, it will be good for you to start seeing the region yourself in geogebra. If you need any help, let me know but that will help you going forward too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that it is more natural to do this in cylindrical coordinates. Then the conditions$$0\leqslant z\leqslant(x^2+y^2)^2\leqslant81$$become$$0\leqslant z\leqslant\rho^4\leqslant81.$$So, since $x=\rho\cos(\theta)$ and $y=\rho\sin(\theta)$, you have$$(x^2+y^2)^2=\bigl(\rho^2\cos^2\theta+\rho^2\sin^2(\theta)\bigr)=\rho^4$$and (since $\rho\geqslant0$)$$\rho^4\leqslant81\iff\rho^2\leqslant3^4\iff0\leqslant\rho\leqslant3.$$Since $M$ doesn't change when you rotate it around the $z$-axis, $\theta$ can take any value from $[0,2\pi]$. So, your integral becomes$$\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^3\int_0^{\rho^4}\rho\bigl(\rho\cos(\theta)+\rho\sin(\theta)+z\bigr)\,\mathrm dz\,\mathrm d\rho\,\mathrm d\theta.$$

Comment: can you please expand on how did you went with the bounds? preferribly explaining with detail since what I said above, I learned this with Khan Academy and it was a while ago and I'm really rusty on the bounds.

Comment: @Acyex Done. I hope that it's clear now.

Comment: Everything's clear as water except for the d(theta). What made you think that M doesn't change when you rotate it around the z-axis? Does this intuition come when you plot it on wolfram/desmos?

Comment: No need. Just note that if $(x,y,z)\in M$, then so does$$\bigl(x\cos(\theta)-y\sin(\theta),x\sin(\theta)+y\cos(\theta),z\bigr).$$That is, if you rotate $(x,y,z)$ around the $z$-axis, then you get another element of $M$.

Comment: Can you expand on: 1. How is x=xcos(theta), y=ysin(theta) and 2. How do you do a rotation around the z-axis? Or just can you recommend any material online to look more into this? Also I tried putting this into geogebra as other people suggested but can't make it to work

Comment: It's $x=\rho\cos(\theta)$ and $y=\rho\sin(\theta)$. And a rotation with angle $\theta$ around the $z$-axis is$$(x,y,z)\mapsto\bigl(x\cos(\theta)-y\sin(\theta),x\sin(\theta)+y\cos(\theta),z\bigr).$$You can learn more about it [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cylindrical_coordinate_system).

Answer (score 2):

In cylindrical coordinates,
$x = r \cos\theta, y = r \sin\theta, x^2 + y^2 = r^2$

The region is given by $0 \leq z \leq r^4 \leq 81$. Please note $r^4 \geq z \geq 0 \implies r \geq  z^{1/4}$ and $r^4 \leq 81 \implies r \leq 3$

So the region is bound between surface $r^4 = z$ and cylinder $r = 3$.

If you integrate with respect to $dr$ first,

$z^{1/4} \leq r \leq 3$, $0 \leq z \leq 81$, $0 \leq \theta \leq 2\pi$

If you integrate with respect to $dz$ first,

$0 \leq z \leq r^4, 0 \leq r \leq 3$, $0 \leq \theta \leq 2\pi$

*Another thing to notice is the symmetry of the region around x and y planes and as $x$ and $y$ are odd functions, their integral will be zero. So the integrand reduces to $z$.*

Answer (score 1):

From $(x^2+y^2)^2\le81$ you get $x^2+y^2\le 0,$ so that's a disk of radius $3$ centered at $(0,0).$ By symmetry,
$$
\iiint\limits_M (x+y) \,dx\,dy\,dz =0
$$
so you just have
$$
\iiint\limits_M z \,dx\,dy\,dz.
$$
If you use polar coordinates, then $(x^2+y^2)^2$ becomes $r^4$ and you have
$$
\int_0^{2\pi} \left( \int_0^3 \left( \int_0^{r^4} z \, dz \right) r\,dr \right) \,d\theta.
$$
Nothing inside the integral with respect to $\theta$ depends on $\theta,$ so you just get $2\pi$ times the inner double integral.

(As usually happens, the expression $r\,dr\,d\theta$ lends itself to computation, but from a geometric point of view it's really $(dr)(r\,d\theta).$)